# Why is this Java array considered two dimensional?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider this code:

```
class arraytest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] a = null , b[] = null;

        b = a;
        System.out.println( b );

    }

}
```

The line

```
b = a;
```

is flagged by the compiler saying:

```
Incompatible types, found int[], required int [][]
```

Why is b considered two dimensional? I realize the "shortcut" declaration

`int[] a = null , b[] = null;`

is to blame, but why does it make the array two dimensional when only one set of brackets have been written? I find this syntax unclear and obfuscating.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take this example:

```
int a, b;
```

Then both a and b are ints, right?  So now take this:

```
int[] a, b;
```

The both a and b are int arrays.  So by adding another set of brackets:

```
int[] a, b[];
```

you **have** added another set of brackets to b.

Either of these would be fine:

```
int[] a = null , b = null;
int a[] = null , b[] = null;
```

or as you say, simply putting them on separate lines would work too (and be much easier to read).

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] a = null , b[] =null;
```

.... it's equal to :

```
int[] a = null;
int[][]b = null;
```

You have to do :

```
int[] a = null , b =null;
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, Java does not have multi-dimensional arrays. Java has arrays of any type. This "any type" may itself be an array. Multi-dimensional arrays are distinctly different, although subtly.

Answer (score 2):

If you take out the `a` declaration, this is what you have:

```
int[] b[] = null;
```

which is, unfortunately, a legal alternative to

```
int[][] b = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was lead to believe that the syntax of allowing the [] after the b was there solely for the C-language crowd who would feel more at home with it.  Unfortunately, it has the side effect of allowing confusing declarations like

```
 int[] b[];
```

which ends up the same as

```
 int[][] b;
```